# XVim Compound Key map

Tags: xcode, vim, xvim

So what I want is a single key map in Xvim that will highlight all of the text inside brackets and then indent using Xcode's indent functionality.

What i've tried

```
nnoremap ,i V aB <C-i>
```

What I would expect is for this to go into visual mode, highlight within the braces, and then indent. It does the first two, but does not indent. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

`<C-i>` / `<Tab>` only works in insert mode; it doesn't indent in visual mode. For that, you can use the `>` command:

```
nnoremap ,i VaB>
```

You don't actually need to go through visual mode; the `>{motion}` command can take the `aB` text object:

```
nnoremap ,i >aB
```